# jps/jvmstat fails on directory paths with space character

Tags: java, windows

The Java Virtual Machine Process Status Tool (jps) lists the instrumented HotSpot Java Virtual Machines (JVMs) on the target system. The package `java.jvmstat` offers the same capabilities. My problem occurs on my windows machine. Eclipse is inside the `C:\Program Files\...` directory. When using jps, not the full path is shown, instead it is truncated on the first space character:

```
jps -l
3623 sun.tools.jps.Jps
3579 C:\Program
```

The same happens using the `java.jvmstat` package. Do I use it in a wrong way or is this an ordinary bug?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you try `jps -m`, for more accurate, is application directory is the one you're looking for?

Comment: This works! But this option is not provided with the jvmstat is it?

Comment: which package of jvmstat are you using? I see it ok.

Answer (score 1):

That's how the utility is written.

Check out line 114 from [MonitoredVmUtil.java](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/jvmstat/sun/jvmstat/monitor/MonitoredVmUtil.java.htm) from the OpenJDK source.  [JPS](http://www.java2s.com/Open-Source/Java-Document/6.0-JDK-Modules-sun/tools/sun/tools/jps/Jps.java.htm) calls this at line 117. It appears as if you'll have to write your own implementation of JPS to avoid that behavior.

Answer (score 0):

At least on command prompt and environment variables a common trick is to use quote marks on a path with spaces. Why don't test it also here? So you write "C:\your path with spaces" and it'll make the trick. Works like charm?

Comment: I propmt the jps tool for an output and what I get is this listed thing above. I cannot embrace it in quotations marks, it's the output I get by the program.

Comment: If the problem is only on your dev machine, why not install your Eclipse again to a custom location without spaces?

Comment: At the same time you can (possibly) have a tool update on your working environment. you can use same workspaces as in old location and only if you have some plugins installed, those will need a reinstall.

Comment: You can always refer to it as C:\Progra~1 the old format for allowing DOS terminals to use directories with long names or those containing spaces
Edit:   it's simply the first 6 letters of the path followed by tilde and a number indicating it's aplha-numeric sorting position - as there's nothing else starting Progra in the C drive "Program Files" gets the ~1